# Problem in importing some Flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, import, package

I can't import the `firebase_auth` package in Flutter.  I did everything they said in the installation part (as shown below).  Other packages are imported and working properly, but `firebase_auth` isn't.

```
name: flash_chat
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.1.0<3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  animated_text_kit: ^2.2.0

  firebase_core: ^0.5.0

  firebase_auth_platform_interface: ^2.0.1

  firebase_auth_web: ^0.3.0+1

  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^2.0.0

  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2

  firebase_analytics: ^6.0.0

  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0

  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - images/
```

And I did the pub get.  Can anybody help me?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There isn't any error but i can't import it at all.

Answer (score 3):

These are a few suggested solutions:

1. Reload your IDE
2. Delete your pubspec.lock file and re run pub get.

Comment: After endless cleaning and version changing and deleting pubspec.lock, it was the IDE restart which worked for me (on VS Code)